# How do I surround specific characters in string with <strong> via preg_replace?

Tags: php, string

At the moment I have a string with no HTML formatting, here's an example:

```
Tue 28 Apr 2015: 10.30am: This is the name of the event.
```

Using PHP I need to make all content that appears before the final colon **bold**, i.e. wrap anything that appears before the final `:` in `<strong>` tags.

The opening strong tag always appears at the beginning, so all I need the script to do is insert the `</strong>` tag **after** the final `:`

Here's the desired output:

```
<strong>Tue 28 Apr 2015: 10.30am:</strong> This is the name of the event.
```

Comment: Please show a sample input and your desired output.

Comment: Wrap it in <strong> tags?

Answer (score 0):

The example you're giving is not very clear. You can achieve what you need with a simple preg_split :

```
<?php
$myString= "Tue 28 Apr 2015: 10.30am: This is the name of the event.";
$myString2=preg_split("/:/", $myString,1);
$myString3="<strong>" .$myString2[0] . "</strong>" . $myString2[1];
echo $myString3;
?>
```